# Weird behavior of UuidCreateSequential

Tags: c++, windows, uuid

I have a software that runs over 2 000 computers on my company, without any issues.

This software, at some time, generate a `GUID` (or `UUID`) using `UuidCreateSequential()` ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379322%28VS.85%29.aspx)).

The call usually returns `RPC_S_OK` on every computer. But on one of them, it always returns `RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY`.

The documentation states that:

> The UuidCreateSequential function
>   returns RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY when the
>   originating computer does not have an
>   ethernet/token ring (IEEE 802.x)
>   address.

However, there seem to be no networking issues with this computer. It has a network card with both valid and unique MAC address and IP address, and it is working perfectly.

What else could cause `UuidCreateSequential()` to always return `RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY` ? Have you ever experienced a similar situation ?

I this can help, the computer which has the issues runs an updated Windows XP, with Service Pack 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I contacted Microsoft and it seems that bug occurs only on Windows XP, when the first byte of the MAC address is superior or equal to `0x80`.

This has been fixed for Windows Vista and Windows Seven. It won't be fixed for Windows XP.

Answer (score 4):

This was a bug in Windows XP and Windows Server 2003.

A MAC address is 48 bits, typically represented as:

```
00-01-02-0A-0B-0C
00:01:02:0a:0b:0c
```

The first three bytes represent an **Organziation**, the remaining three bytes are whatever numbering scheme that organization wants to use. Organization ID's are handed out by the IEEE.

For all public MAC addresses, the 2nd-lowest (2nd least significant bit) of the first byte will be zero. If you wanted to generate your own **local** MAC addresses, you could set the bit to 1:

```
02-01-02-0A-0B-0C

   02   -   01   -   02   -   0A   -   0B   -   0C
/¯¯¯¯¯¯\ /¯¯¯¯¯¯\ /¯¯¯¯¯¯\ /¯¯¯¯¯¯\ /¯¯¯¯¯¯\ /¯¯¯¯¯¯\
00000010-00000001-00000010-00001010-00001011-00001100
      ^
      |
      +- 0: Universal 
         1: Locally Administered
```

Or the image lifted from Wikipedia:

[image]

### Windows checked the wrong bit

The bug in Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 is that they were were checking the wrong bit. They were mistakenly checking the *high* bit:

I hate to throw Raymond under the bus, but [here's an example of the incorrect information](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx):

> The last 48 bits are the unique address of the computer's network card. If the computer does not have a network card, **set the top bit and use a random number generator for the other 47. No valid network card will have the top bit set in its address**, so there is no possibility that a GUID generated from a computer without a network card will accidentally collide with a GUID generated from a computer with a network card.

Emphasis mine. The correction would be to say that:

> ...set the 2nd least significant bit... No valid network card will have the 2nd least significant bit set.

## Testing

I tested this on my computer. My computer has a MAC address of:

```
‎C8-60-00-12-34-56  (Ok, i changed the serialized number, but it is a Realtek)
```

If we were to follow the Windows XP rules, this MAC address would be *"locally administered"*, and UuidCreateSequential would return **RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY**

When i run `UuidCreateSequential` on Windows 7, it runs fine:

```
{FBE65AFC-2588-11E5-9F09-C86000123456}
{FBE65AFD-2588-11E5-9F09-C86000123456}
{FBE65AFE-2588-11E5-9F09-C86000123456}
{FBE65AFF-2588-11E5-9F09-C86000123456}
```

But if i run it on a Windows XP machine with the same (or similar) MAC address:

[image]

The function fails:

> 0x720  A UUID that is valid only on this computer has been allocated.

## Fix

This bug of checking the wrong bit of the MAC address was documented in:

- [KB2569646: UuidCreateSequential API may return RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY(1824) Error.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2569646) *(June 22, 2011)*

  > This problem occurs because the UuidCreateSequential API wrongly recognizes a MAC address as an invalid address if the first bits of the MAC address is ON(1).

It was also documented in `UuidCreateSequential`, along with:

- [KB981080: You receive a warning when you use the UUIDGEN.exe command or the UuidCreateSequential function on a computer that has a valid network adapter address](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/981080)[6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379322(v=vs.85).aspx):

  > This issue occurs because the operating system incorrectly evaluates MAC addresses of network adapters.

There was an associated hotfix, but i don't believe it was fixed beyond that (i.e. no formal fix in a service pack).

You have three choices:

- change your MAC address in your Windows XP settings to not have the high-bit set
- upgrade to Windows Vista or newer
- if the function returns **RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY**, and you are before Windows Vista (`dwMajor < 6`), then assume it actually succeeded (***Dangerous!***)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps its a security issue, is the user making the call an Administrator? If not, the NIC driver may be failing to supply the MAC address.

As long as the UUID is used for something local to that machine, then accepting this error as a valid result may be OK.

If the UUID must be guaranteed globally unique (e.g. asset registration) then asking another box (e.g. the registration server) might be a better idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and for the typo-fix ;) !). Unfortunately, the UUID must be globally unique and I can't change the software (at least, not too much) and make it ask another box for an UUID.

I wonder why this is only happening on one computer.

Comment: Does this machine have a different NIC and/or driver version to the other working machines? In that case, try uninstalling the NIC driver, rebooting, and when the NIC is re-detected using the manufacturer's version instead of the Microsoft one (or vice versa).